# Splitting and concatenating strings pasted in excel

Tags: excel, split, concatenation

I am trying to find a way to split the below strings using excel functions(pasted in excel from nessus)

```
Share: c$ path: /some/path/to/file.txt   (1234567890123456)
Share: d$ path: /some/path/to/file1.txt   (1234567890123)
```

so that next two cells has

```
c:/some/path/to/file.txt
```

followed by

```
1234567890123456
```

How can I do this? I have been trying to use the LEFT, MID, RIGHT, SEARCH and CONCATENATE function but not getting it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

edit: Forgot to mention the format:

The values that change are in <>

```
Share: <drive>$ path: <path to file>   (<number>)
```

Comment: Does the first desired extraction always end it ".txt"? 
Is it always preceded by the string "path:"? Is the second desired extraction always at the very end of the string? Is it always enclosed in parentheses?

Comment: where are you trying to use concatenation? before and after string are not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the string to be split is in cell A1:

```
=MID(A1,8,1)&":/"&LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("path: ",A1,1),LEN(A1)),SEARCH("   (",MID(A1,SEARCH("path: ",A1,1),LEN(A1)),1)-1)
```

The above formula will get you the `c:/some/path/to/file.txt` portion, and the below formula will get you the `1234567890123456` portion:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("   (",A1,1)+4,LEN(A1)),LEN(MID(A1,SEARCH("   (",A1,1)+4,LEN(A1)))-1)
```

Please note that these formulas are based on a couple things not changing in terms of the format of the string (e.g. the spacing between the file path and the number is consistent, consistent use of parentheses, the string always starting with `Share:`, `$ path:` always following the drive and always preceding the file path, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use two following formulas:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)- FIND("(",A1)-1)    
=MID(A1,FIND("Share: ",A1)+7,1)  & ":"  & MID(A1,FIND("path: ",A1)+6,FIND("(",A1)-FIND("path: ",A1)-8)
```

The first returns the file length, the second returns the file name. It is better to use FIND because it is case sensitive.

Those formulas are based on finding following parts in the text: `(`, `)`, `Share:` and `path:`.

If you need to work with longer sharenames you can write the first formula like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Share: ",A1)+7,1)  & ":"  & MID(A1,FIND("path: ",A1)+6,FIND("(",A1)-FIND("path: ",A1)-8)
```

But if it is on Windows you would need to use UNC path like `\\servername\sharename\path`.